# Fetch on backbone isn't populate my template

Tags: backbone.js

I did a fetch in my collection and I did a console.log() and it's working but when I set to my template not show the values.

in my View is it:

```
       var reposCollection = new Sice.Collections.RepositoryList();
       reposCollection.fetch();
       this.$el.html(this.template({collection: reposCollection.models}));
```

my template is it:

```
      <% _.each(collection, function(repos) { %>
        <tr>        
          <td><%= repos.attributes.name %></td>
          <td><%= repos.attributes.description %></td>
          <td><%= repos.attributes.language %></td>
       </tr>
     <% }); %>
```

I don't know what is happening!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your template is being rendered before your `fetch` is completed. You need to call the rendering code in the `success` callback of `fetch`:

```
var reposCollection = new Sice.Collections.RepositoryList();
reposCollection.fetch({
    success: (collection, response, options) => {
        this.$el.html(this.template({collection: collection.models}));
    }
});
```

[Backbone.Collection.prototype.fetch documentation](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-fetch)